# In ExtJS, How Can You Loop Through Menu Items?

Tags: javascript, extjs

How can you loop through all the items in an ExtJS toolbar menu, for example to change their icons?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Use the 'each' method of the [MixedCollection](http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/dev/docs/?class=Ext.util.MixedCollection) instance in the button's menu.

Assuming a definition like:

```
var pnl = new Ext.Panel({
    tbar: [
        {
            itemId: 'a_btn',
            text: 'A menu button',
            menu: {items: [
                {
                    text: 'Item 1'
                },
                {
                    text: 'Item 2'
                }
            ]}
        }
    ]
});
```

You can then later do:

```
var btn = pnl.getTopToolbar().get('a_btn');

btn.menu.items.each(function( item ) {
    item.setIconClass('');
});
```

Comment: Wouldn't have explained it better.

Comment: Absolutely fantastic- many thanks indeed for the prompt and clear answer! :)

Comment: ExtJS 5.0.1 API link: http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.0.1/#!/api/Ext.util.MixedCollection