# Sencha Touch - Accessing Associated-Model Store JSON via Nested Looping

Tags: json, sencha-touch, nested-loops

I've been lurking on Stack Overflow for quite some time now, and have found quite a number of very helpful answers. Many thanks to the community! I hope to be able to contribute my own helpful answers before too long.

In the meantime, I have another issue I can't figure out. I am using Sencha Touch to create a Web-based phone app and I'm having trouble using a nested loop to iterate through some JSON. I can grab the first level of data, but not the items nested within that first level. There is a somewhat [related ExtJS thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3523733/in-extjs-how-can-you-loop-through-menu-items), but I decided to create my own since ExtJS and Touch diverge in subtle yet important ways. Anyway, here is some code to show where I am:

JSON (truncated - the JSON is PHP/MYSQL-generated, and there are currently actually three sub levels with "title", all of which I can access. It's the sub level "items" through which I can't iterate):

```
{
"lists": [
    {
        "title": "Groceries",
        "id": "1",
        "items": [
            {
                "text": "contact solution - COUPON",
                "listId": "1",
                "id": "4",
                "leaf": "true" 
            },
            {
                "text": "Falafel (bulk)",
                "listId": "1",
                "id": "161",
                "leaf": "true" 
            },
            {
                "text": "brita filters",
                "listId": "1",
                "id": "166",
                "leaf": "true" 
            }
        ] 
    } 
]
```

}

Store:

```
var storeItms = new Ext.data.Store({
    model: 'Lists',
    proxy: {
        type: 'ajax',
        method: 'post',
        url : LIST_SRC,
        extraParams: {action: 'gtLstItms'},
        reader: {
            type: 'json',
            root: 'lists'
        }
    }
});
```

Working Loop:

```
storeItms.on('load', function(){
    var lstArr = new Array();
    storeItms.each(function(i) {
        var title = i.data.title;
        lstArr.push(i.data.title);
    });
    console.log(lstArr);
});
```

Non-working Nested Loop:

```
storeItms.on('load', function(){
    var lstArr = new Array();
    storeItms.each(function(i) {
        var title = i.data.title;
        var id = i.data.id;
        title.items.each(function(l) {
            lstArr.push(l.data.text);
        });
    });
    console.log(lstArr);
});
```

The non-working nested loop gives me the error "Cannot call method 'each' of undefined", in reference to 'title.items.each...'

I suspect this is because I've not set title to be a key to set up a key:value pair, so it just sees a list of strings...but I'm kind of at a loss.

I should mention that the store is populated via two Models that have been associated with one another. I know that the Store can access everything because I am able to do nested iterating via an XTemplate.

Any help will be much appreciated and hopefully returned to the community in kind before too long!'

-Eric

Answer (score 0):

Eric, why the loop?

If your models are associated in the same way that the JSON is nested, then you should just be able to set autoLoad:true on the store, sit back and enjoy.

Anyway, on the assumption that you are needing these arrays for some other unrelated reason, the problem is that you are trying .each on

```
i.data.title.items
```

Surely you should be iterating through

```
i.data.items
```

Also, if the object is a model, you can use .get() instead of the data object:

```
var title = i.get('title);
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, James! The complete data structure comprises various lists (Groceries, To Do, etc), as well as items associated with each list. I can't simply iterate through all items in the complete set; rather, I need to iterate through the lists, and during each list iteration I need to iterate through that list's items.

Comment: The reason I need to do this is to create a FormPanel that allows a user to edit the items in a list. Since the number of items in each list is changeable, I can't simply set up a form of with a set number of textfields and populate it accordingly. The fields have to be created and populated on the fly when a certain list is chosen for editing.

I am able to pull this off via jQuery by simply using span tag classes to generate input tags around each item in a list, but I'm trying to do accomplish this more "natively", so to speak.

Answer (score 0):

Using new sencha touch 2 framework, you can create associations within the models exactly the same way how your json is returned. 
Check [Sencha Touch 2 Model Document](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/1-1/#!/api/Ext.data.Model) which tells you the various config options on Model.
You may refer to this example of [ST2 Nested List](https://github.com/kostysh/Sencha-Touch-2.0-MVC-test-application-with-NestedList) .

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

"title" is not a enumerable object, its a string. To iterate a string you'll need to split it to convert it into an array.

Also, instead of using Ext.each try a simple for (var x in obj) {} or for (var xc in obj.prop) {} If that works then the ext.each method should work as well but if ext cannot iterate the object it will just quietly fail.